# Can't find built-in class kotlin.collections.List

Tags: android, list, kotlin

I get this error -> java.lang.AssertionError: Can't find built-in class kotlin.collections.List
sometimes when I launch my application. This crash sometimes appear and sometimes do not.

My code is

```
SmartRecyclerAdapter
        .items(listItems) // here exception is being thrown
        .map(Header::class, CustomEventVH::class)
        .map(Appointment::class, UpcomingVH::class)
        .add(OnCustomViewEventListener{
            startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), ActivityAddAttachment::class.java))
        })
        .into<SmartRecyclerAdapter>(binding!!.recyclerview)
```

The error appears at .items(listItems)